# Prolog, List of lists contains another list exactly

Tags: prolog, declarative-programming

What I basically want to achieve is, that given a list of lists *A*, I want a predicate that checks if the elements of a list *B* are **exactly** contained in list *A*.

So for example:

**A** = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
**B** = [1,2,3,4,5]

and

**A** = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
**B** = [2,5,3,4,1]

Would result to true, but

**A** = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
**B** = [1,2,3,4]

and

**A** = [[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]]
**B** = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

would both result to false.

is this possible in prolog?

Exactly means: 
Order doesn't matter, it just has to contain all the elements.
Also, imagine that the *B* list doesn't contain duplicates.
So if *A* would contain duplicates, we should get false as a result.

Comment: Of course this is possible. In prolog, there are *predicates*, not *functions*. They're not really the same thing and don't have the same behavior. You should look at `flatten/2` which will make this simple.

Comment: Still not clear what **exactly** means, based on your examples. Does the order matter? What happens with repetitions?

Comment: [append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2)/2 could be and answer

Comment: @lurker and Boris, thank you for your quick responses, I edited my question to give you a better description of my problem. Keep in mind that I am new to prolog, so there are no 'trivial' answers for me.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. Do you mean, "the set of elements in the nested list A is the same as the set of elements of list B"? Or maybe, "the stably sorted elements in nested list A is the same as the stably sorted list B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial answer:

```
?- flatten([[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]], [1,2,3,4,5]).
true.

?- flatten([[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]], [1,2,3,4]).
false.

?- flatten([[1,2],[3,4],[5],[]], [1,2,3,4,5,6]).
false.
```

Or,

```
foo(A, B) :- % because I don't know how to call it
    flatten(A, B).
```

If you are talking about sets:

```
bar(A, B) :-
    flatten(A, A_flat),
    sort(A_flat, A_sorted),
    sort(B, A_sorted).
```

You can use `msort/2` if you don't want to remove duplicates.

If the question is, "how do I implement `flatten/2`", you can find several answers on SO.